# Running Weekly, monthly, Quarterly Returns for S&P500

Tags: python, pandas, resample

I have a DataFrame containing Date as an index and S&P500 closing prices.

Next I compute % change on Daily Basis

```
data["daily_return"] = data["Close"].pct_change()
```

I can compute Returns as follows:

```
data_weekly = 100*data["daily_return"].resample("W").agg(lambda x: (x + 1).prod() - 1)
dwk['SP500'] = data_weekly
```

Resample shrinks daily data into smaller weekly data. Instead How do I compute running Weekly Return, i.e., I need to see partial weekly returns every week that gets reset at the beginning of the week or month etc?

I tried the following that yields useful info, but not quite the same info I am looking for

```
data_weekly = 100*data["daily_return"].resample("W").agg(lambda x: (x + 1).prod() - 1)
dwk['SP500'] = data_weekly
```

Comment: The answer you want depends on the structure of your data, and other constraints. It would be helpful to share a working example, with a couple weeks of data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Indeed your post is missing an [mre] for this site. Please take a look at [ask] for guidance, and at some point, do take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added excel data to the post based on Arthur's suggestion